# Click on NavigationDrawer does not change Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make an application on Android with a ViewPager filled with 2 Fragments as a start and a NavigationDrawer to have a side menu and be able to navigate between all Fragments.
But the method "OnClickListener" overloaded for the NavigationDrawer does not respond when the OnClick event is done. I have already tried to change the XML parameters of the drawer items and the list but no changes appears.
Please if some have a few minutes to check that, thanks a lot

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private String[] drawerItemsList;
private ListView myDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ViewPager pager;
private FragmentManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(manager));

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerItemsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    myDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer);
    myDrawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_item, drawerItemsList));

    myDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new MyDrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Appli");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private class MyDrawerItemClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {
        displayView(pos);
    }
    private void displayView(int position) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#333"
    android:divider="#AAA"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"  />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the last file

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch(pos) {
    case 0: return ArtistFragment.newInstance();
    case 1: return AlbumFragment.newInstance();
    default: return ArtistFragment.newInstance();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check the navigation drawer menu implementation from the sample app in developers guide.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html